# using Reduce/do.call with ifelse

Tags: r, higher-order-functions

This is purely a curiosity (learning more about Reduce).  There are way better methods to achieve what I'm doing and I am not interested in them.

Some people use a series of nested `ifelse` commands to recode/look up something.  Maybe it looks like this:

```
set.seed(10); x <- sample(letters[1:10], 300, T)
ifelse(x=="a", 1, 
    ifelse(x=="b", 2,
    ifelse(x=="c", 3, 
    ifelse(x=="d", 4, 5))))
```

Is there a way to use either `do.call` or `Reduce` with the `ifelse` to get the job done a little more eloquently?

Comment: Great question.  Of course, in practice, something like `sapply(x, function(x) switch(x, a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, 5` is probably cleanest.

Comment: @Richie Thanks.  I'd actually approach this with a look up table using environments or standard indexing with `match` but I wanted to see if `Reduce` or `do.call` could be applied to this problem.

Comment: As in: `match(x, letters[1:4], nomatch=5)`

Comment: yep just like that.  I think `Reduce` is out on this one but `do.call` may be used somehow if you passed everything as a list, maybe.

Comment: Yeah, it looks a lot like `Reduce` should work, but fundamentally it's passing three inputs not two.  It may be possible to kludge it with a list of list[2]'s or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
> library(gsubfn)
> strapply(x, ".", list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, 5), simplify = TRUE)
  [1] 5 4 5 5 1 3 3 3 5 5 5 5 2 5 4 5 1 3 4 5 5 5 5 4 5 5 5 3 5 4 5 1 2 5 5 5 5
 [38] 5 5 5 3 3 1 5 3 2 1 5 2 5 4 5 3 5 2 5 5 5 4 5 1 2 5 4 5 5 5 5 1 3 1 5 5 5
 [75] 1 5 4 5 3 3 5 5 3 5 3 1 5 3 2 2 5 5 5 5 4 5 3 5 5 1 4 1 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
[112] 5 2 5 5 5 3 5 5 5 2 4 4 5 3 3 5 4 5 5 5 1 5 3 4 3 5 5 2 5 5 3 1 5 2 5 5 5
[149] 1 5 5 2 1 2 4 2 2 3 5 2 5 5 5 5 5 3 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 2 3 5 4 4 2 5 5 5
[186] 5 5 5 5 2 1 1 1 5 5 5 5 3 5 5 3 5 5 5 2 5 5 5 3 5 5 5 5 5 1 5 5 5 5 2 2 5
[223] 5 5 4 3 4 5 5 4 5 5 5 3 5 3 5 5 5 5 4 5 5 1 5 5 2 5 5 5 2 5 5 3 2 5 4 5 2
[260] 5 5 3 5 5 1 4 3 5 4 5 2 5 5 3 5 5 5 5 5 1 1 5 2 5 1 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
[297] 5 1 5 2
```

Comment: I'm not seeing an `ifelse` and a `do.call` or `Reduce` function anywhere :)

Comment: Try `do.call <- strapply` and then repeat the above with `do.call` in place of `strapply`.

Comment: I see the Summer of Love has given way to the Autumn of Discontent instead :-D

Comment: Of course there is also `dont.call <- function() q("no")` .  (Caution: Not to be used by those under age or unfamiliar with R.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt. It is neither beautiful nor does it use ifelse:

```
f <- function(w,s) {
  if(is.null(s$old)) 
    w$output[is.na(w$output)] <- s$new
  else 
    w$output[w$input==s$old] <- s$new
  return(w)
}

set.seed(10); x <- sample(letters[1:10], 300, T)

subst <- list(
  list(old="a", new=1), 
  list(old="b", new=2),
  list(old="c", new=3),
  list(old="d", new=4),
  list(old=NULL, new=5)
)
workplace <- list(
  input=x,
  output=rep(NA, length(x))
)

Reduce(f, subst, workplace)
```